# Expression must have class type error in C++ Can't get it to work

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ program that checks if a text-file I read in is acyclic, and if it is, then I topologically sort it. When I try to create an object for dfsgraph and topologicalsort classes in main shown below, it underlines temp and temp1 and gives me the error of "Expression must have class type"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "topologicalsort.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>
#include "dfsgraph.h"

int main()
{
std::ifstream in;
std::ofstream out;

std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << in.rdbuf();
std::string test = buffer.str();
std::cout << test << std::endl << std::endl;

ifstream fileIn;
ofstream fileOut;
fileIn.open("graphin-DAG.txt");

string input;
string output;

if (fileIn.fail())
{
    cout << "Error with file";
}

for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
{

    while (getline(fileIn, input)) {
        //fileIn >> input;
        string numbers = input;
        dfsgraph* temp;
        topologicalsort* temp1;
        //dfsgraph* temp = new dfsgraph();
        //topologicalsort* temp1 = new topologicalsort();

        temp.isCyclic(numbers);

        dfsgraph dfsg(int verts);
        //if (temp.isCyclic(numbers)()) {

        if (temp.isCyclic(numbers)) {
            cout << "Graph is acyclic";
            temp1.topologicalSort(numbers);
        }

        else {
            cout << "Graph is not acyclic";
        }

        return 0;       
    }
}

fileIn.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's `dfsgraph` actually?

Comment: It decides if it is a cycle or not

Comment: Make sure you have classes named dfsgraph and topologicalsort... intialize your pointers and use -> not dot to access your pointers temp and temp1 members.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code is horrible.  Not only does it hide the type named `dfsgraph` with a local identifier, it declares a function, so the type of the identifier is not even the same as the type with the same name.

```
dfsgraph dfsgraph(int verts);
```

Give your local variable a unique name and use correct direct-initialization syntax:

```
dfsgraph dfsg(verts);
```

or

```
dfsgraph dfsg{verts};
```

Comment: That line of code is unnecessary anyways. I updated my code, but I don't know how to show you guys without making a new question.

Comment: @ms01249: There's an "edit" link under your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40077519/edit  You can add updated versions below (don't remove the original version you asked about).

Answer (score 0):

What are these lines supposed to do?

```
std::ifstream in;
std::ofstream out;

std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << in.rdbuf();
std::string test = buffer.str();
std::cout << test << std::endl << std::endl;
```

`in` is default constructed, there is nothing to read.

And even if the file `fail()`, you are running the for loop.

`string numbers` is declared twice.

**Ben Voigt** said the rest.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe just:

```
...
dfsgraph* temp = new dfsgraph();
topologicalsort* temp1 = new topologicalsort();
...
```

Comment: That gives a no instance of constructor error by the parentheses.

Comment: C++ is not Java, automatic lifetime is a good thing when there is no garbage collector (and even when there is)